# ¿Cómo desplazar un JPanel a un costado?

Tags: java-swing

Tengo este JFrame que tiene dos paneles uno gris (que es el de atrás) y el panel en el que se inicia sesión. Mi objetivo es que cuando toque el botón **entrar** el JPanel se mueva de forma visible hacia la izquierda hasta desaparecer, dejando el panel de atrás visible.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que tengo hasta ahora

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();   //panel de atrás
panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
panel.setBounds(0, 0, 700, 371);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
panel.setLayout(null);

JPanel panel_1 = new JPanel();
panel_1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
panel_1.setBounds(0, 0, 233, 371);
panel.add(panel_1);
panel_1.setLayout(null);

JButton btnEntrar = new JButton("Entrar");
btnEntrar.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
btnEntrar.setFont(new Font("Tw Cen MT", Font.PLAIN, 16));
btnEntrar.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
btnEntrar.setBounds(95, 280, 89, 23);
panel_1.add(btnEntrar);
...
```

Inventé algo como esto pero se desplaza muy rápido

```
btnEntrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            for(int i = 233; i >= 0; i--) {
                panel_1.setBounds(panel_1.getX(), panel_1.getY(), i, panel_1.getHeight());
                try {
                    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // TODO Bloque catch generado automáticamente
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                panel_1.repaint();
            }
            panel_1.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como utilizas nanosegundos en esta linea:

```
    TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.sleep(1000);
```

le estas diciendo al panel que cada 1x10⁻⁶ segundos cambie su posicion, lo que es demasiado rapido, como solucion, cambia el tiempo de demora a una cifra mas alta, si pones 10 millones, te quedara cada 0.01 segundos, y a mil millones, se cambiara cada segundo